# Remove rows from DataFrame that contain numbers from 0 to 9

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column (ResourceName) that contains different types of names:

```
Testvalue
F424221M
F844071
water
```

I would like to **remove** the rows that **contain numbers** (row 2 and 3), so that the row with Testvalue remains. I could not find an appropriate solution for this.

Something like :

```
df1 = df1[(df1['ResourceName']) != '**CONTAINS ANY NUMBER**']
```

Comment: Would you please show your OWN efforts to us first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the vectorised [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) and the regex pattern `\d` to see if the string contains any digits to create the boolean mask and use `~` to negate it:

```
In [173]:
df[~df['Testvalue'].str.contains('\d')]

Out[173]:
  Testvalue
2     water
```

Here the `contains` generates the following boolean mask:

```
In [174]:
df['Testvalue'].str.contains('\d')

Out[174]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: Testvalue, dtype: bool
```